# Aginity Workbench for Redshift - to_timestamp conversion issue

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, aginity

I am facing an issue when using the function **to_timestamp()** on Aginity Workbench for AWS Redshift. For some reason I don't understand, 2 hours are added to the timestamp i am trying to create.

I have been looking for a solution but couldn't find anything similar, can someone help me solving this problem ?

---

The following code :

```
select
'2017-10-17 10:30:00' test,
to_timestamp('2017-10-17 10:30:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') test_converted
```

Retrieves :

test = 2017-10-17 10:30:00

test_converted = 2017-10-17 **12:30:00**

Comment: looks like a time zone thing. are you UTC+2? what do you get with '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamp and '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamptz and '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC'

Comment: Agreed, '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamptz gives '2017-10-17 12:30:00' and '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamptz at time zone 'UTC' gives me '2017-10-17 10:30:00'.
What are the "::" doing ? If XX::timestamp equals to_timestamp(XX,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') then it fixes my problem.

Comment: please see my answer below and "accept"  if it is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use :: to cast types in postgres and redshift, so your code would be

```
select '2017-10-17 10:30:00'::timestamp;
```

this would resolve your issue.

(I think your previous code was converting to local timezone)